Can we use a first argument type to determine (with an indexed schema) if we can use another argument, while being fully type-safe
If we have a schema describing paths, nested methods, and then their characteristics:
interface Schema {
  'aaa': {
    'zzz': { result: 'AAA-ZZZ', action: { path: 'bbb', method: 'xxx' } }
    'xxx': { result: 'AAA-XXX', action: { path: 'ccc', method: 'zzz' } }
  };
  'bbb': {
    'xxx': { result: 'BBB-XXX', action: { path: 'ccc', method: 'zzz' } }
  };
  'ccc': {
    'zzz': { result: 'CCC-ZZZ', action: { path: 'aaa', method: 'zzz' }, content: string }
  }
}

The goal is to type a function that will take an action description, and only when necessary use a second argument to get the content.
For example:
doSomething({ path: 'aaa', method: 'xxx' }) // return "AAA-XXX", no second argument.

doSomething({ path: 'aaa', method: 'xxx' }, "content string") // Should fail because this path/method does not use a content.

doSomething({ path: "ccc", method: "zzz" }, "content string") // return "CCC-ZZZ", takes a second argument to specify the content.

doSomething({ path: "ccc", method: "zzz" }) // Should fail because a second argument is missing

I found this answer that helped a lot building something that approach the desired result.
Here is what I have with a more simple schema:
interface Schema {
  'aaa': { result: string };
  'bbb': { result: number };
  'ccc': { result: boolean, content: string };
}

type DoSomethingArgs = {
  [Key in keyof Schema]: [key: Key, ...rest: Schema[Key] extends {
    content: infer InferredContent
  } ? [specificContent: InferredContent] : []]
}[keyof Schema]

function doSomething<
  Args extends DoSomethingArgs,
  Key extends Args[0],
  Out = Schema[Key]['result']
>(...args: Args): Out {

  return undefined as Out; // Not the point.
}


// Calling tests

const res_1 = doSomething("aaa"); // OK, result is string
const res_2 = doSomething("bbb"); // OK, result is number
const res_3 = doSomething("bbb", 'wrong content'); // OK: TS2345: Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter of type never

const res_4 = doSomething("ccc", 123); // OK: TS2345: Argument of type number is not assignable to parameter of type string
const res_5 = doSomething("ccc", 'some content'); // OK, result is boolean

const res_6 = doSomething("ccc"); // OK: Should fail because content is required
//                             ^^^^^
//  TS2345: Argument of type ["ccc"] is not assignable to parameter of type DoSomethingArgs
//    Type ["ccc"] is not assignable to type [key: "ccc", specificContent: string]
//      Source has 1 element(s) but target requires 2

/* All okay \o/, but example is too simple */

I managed to have a result with the desired schema, but the code is using // @ts-ignore:
interface Schema {
  'aaa': {
    'zzz': { result: 'AAA-ZZZ', action: { path: 'bbb', method: 'xxx' } }
    'xxx': { result: 'AAA-XXX', action: { path: 'ccc', method: 'zzz' } }
  };
  'bbb': {
    'xxx': { result: 'BBB-XXX', action: { path: 'ccc', method: 'zzz' } }
  };
  'ccc': {
    'zzz': { result: 'CCC-ZZZ', action: { path: 'aaa', method: 'zzz' }, content: string }
  }
}


type DoSomethingArgs = {
  [Path in keyof Schema]: {
    [Method in keyof Schema[Path]]: [
      out: Schema[Path][Method] extends { result: infer Result } ? Result : never,
      action: {
        path: Path,
        method: Method
      },
      ...rest: Schema[Path][Method] extends { content: infer InferredContent } ? [specificContent: InferredContent]
        : [],
    ]
  }[keyof Schema[Path]]
}[keyof Schema]


function doSomething<
  Args extends DoSomethingArgs extends [unknown, ...infer Rest] ? Rest : never,
  

  // Here is the issue !
  // Without the ts-ignore we have the following errors:
  // TS2536: Type Args[0]["method"] cannot be used to index type Schema[Args[0]["path"]]
  // TS2536: Type "result" cannot be used to index type Schema[Args[0]["path"]][Args[0]["method"]]

  // @ts-ignore
  Out extends Schema [Args[0]["path"]] [Args[0]["method"]] ['result']
>(...args: Args): Out {

  return undefined as Out; // Not the point.
}



// Calling tests

declare const schema: Schema;


const res_00 = doSomething({ path: '', method: '' }); // Ok: Fails because action type is incorrect

const res_01 = doSomething({ path: 'aaa', method: 'xxx' }); // Ok, return type is "AAA-XXX"

const res_10 = doSomething({ path: "bbb", method: "xxx" }); // Ok, return type is "BBB-XXX"
const res_11 = doSomething(schema.aaa.zzz.action, 'asd'); // Ok: Fails, because AAA/ZZZ action's (pointing to bbb/xxx)  does not have a content

const res_20 = doSomething(schema.bbb.xxx.action, 'content string'); // Ok, return type is "CCC-ZZZ"
const res_21 = doSomething({ path: "ccc", method: "zzz" }, 'content string'); // Ok, return type is "CCC-ZZZ"
const res_22 = doSomething(schema.bbb.xxx.action); // Ok: Fails, because content is missing

const res_30 = doSomething(schema.ccc.zzz.action); // Ok: return type is "AAA-ZZZ"
const res_31 = doSomething(schema.ccc.zzz.action, 'asd'); // Ok: Fails because CCC/ZZZ action's (pointing to aaa/zzz) does not have a content

Is it possible to not use @ts-ignore in this case?

Does this approach meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Very interesting ! It seems to match the needs indeed. I will have a to check with my complete use-case but this approach solves the issue of the nested object keys.
I don't entirely get why the type is inferred differently if the Path and Method are referenced in the parameter slot instead of a generic "Action".

Is it a general bad practice / or has it perf impact to use the generics for returnType and args types and specifies everything in front of the method ?

• Are you saying you need to wait until you check something before confirming if I should write an answer or not? • I didn't bother to try to understand your type, as it seemed needlessly complicated to me and apparently doesn't work; is that required for this question? It doesn't seem to be in scope, since you're asking "can this be done" and not "why isn't my failed attempt working" which is much more involved. • I don't understand your last question with generics and performance. Is it directly relevant to this question or is it a followup?

• Sorry for being unclear, I checked your approach against my use-case and made it work, so yes you can add an answer.
I think it will be useful !
• The type is complicated because I'm working with a generated type, and I do not have many leverage on it.
• The question "why isn't my failed attempt working" is also of interest and I think my follow up comment about generics and performance is my poor expression of that exact question.

My inclination would be to write doSomething()'s call signature as follows:
declare function doSomething<P extends keyof Schema, M extends keyof Schema[P]>
  (
    a: { path: P, method: M },
    ...rest: Schema[P][M] extends { content: infer C } ? [C] : []
  ): Schema[P][M] extends { result: infer R } ? R : never;

The function is naturally generic in two type arguments: P corresponding to path and M corresponding to method.  We constrain the generics so that they can't be invalid.
After the initial parameter, I use a rest parameter of a tuple type which is either one element long of type Schema[P][M]["content"] if that exists, or zero elements long if it doesn't. This will either require or prohibit a second argument when called, depending on that content type.  Note that I wrote it with an inferred conditional type; if you try to do a lot of deep indexing directly, TypeScript usually gets confused (see microsoft/TypeScript#21760) so I'm avoiding that.
For the return type I do the same thing with Schema[P][M]["result"].

Let's test it out:
doSomething({ path: '', method: '' }); // error, expected 2 args
const res_01 = doSomething({ path: 'aaa', method: 'xxx' });
// const res_01: "AAA-XXX"

const res_10 = doSomething({ path: "bbb", method: "xxx" });
// const res_10: "BBB-XXX"
doSomething(schema.aaa.zzz.action, 'asd'); // error, expected 1 arg

const res_20 = doSomething(schema.bbb.xxx.action, 'content string');
// const res_20: "CCC-ZZZ"
const res_21 = doSomething({ path: "ccc", method: "zzz" }, 'content string');
// const res_21: "CCC-ZZZ"
doSomething(schema.bbb.xxx.action); // error, expected 2 args

const res_30 = doSomething(schema.ccc.zzz.action);
// const res_30: "AAA-ZZZ"
doSomething(schema.ccc.zzz.action, 'asd'); // error, expected 1 arg

Looks good. All your tests behave as desired.
Playground link to code
